# iOS custom view cover the system keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, cover

How do I make a custom view cover the system keyboard？
As we all know, the level of the system keyboard is very high, and the custom view cannot be covered，the system keyboard is always at the top.
Telegram APP make it，How to make it？

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [ask].